# service-worker.js not receiving message

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

Im trying to get my service-worker.js to execute skipWaiting when a new service worker gets uploaded. However, im not successful in performing this. Please note that my main framework is reactjs

Tried following this guide (https://deanhume.com/displaying-a-new-version-available-progressive-web-app/) and adapting the code to mine but wasnt successful either.

Currently Im only able to receive notifications that the a new service worker is available, this was observed and confirmed under the browser-dev-tools as well.

Here's my code:
`index.js`

```
import "@babel/polyfill";

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

function check() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(reg => {
            reg.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
                // A wild service worker has appeared in reg.installing!
                const newWorker = reg.installing;
                newWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                    // Has network.state changed?
                    switch (newWorker.state) {
                        case 'installed':
                            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                                // new update available
                                window.serviceWorkerCallback('new_version')
                                newWorker.postMessage({ action: 'skipWaiting' });
                                console.log("New Version!")
                            }
                            // No update available
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    };
}

check();
```

`window.serviceWorkerCallback('new_version')` from `index.js` activates `_serviceWorkerCallback` function under `App.js` which triggers my reload command. After refreshing my page, I could see that the new service worker is still waiting. Below is my reload command code:

`App.js`:

```
    _serviceWorkerCallback = (state) => {
        if (state === 'new_version') {
            this.setState({
                hasNewVersion: true
            });
        }
    }

    _renderNewVersion = () => {
        return (
            <Snackbar
                style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}
                anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'center' }}
                open={this.state.hasNewVersion}
                message={<span>A new version is available</span>}
                action={<Button color="secondary" size="small" onClick={this._handleRefresh}>Refresh</Button>}
            />
        );
    }

    _handleRefresh = (value) => {
        this.setState({
            hasNewVersion: false,
        });
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

Here is `service-worker.js` :

```
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    console.log('Skipping');
    if (event.data.action === 'skipWaiting') {
        self.skipWaiting();
    }
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    console.log('Fetching');
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    return response;
                }
                return fetch(event.request);
            })
    );
});

_handleRefresh = (value) => {
    this.setState({
        hasNewVersion: false,
    });
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Im expecting `newWorker.postMessage({ action: 'skipWaiting' });` to trigger `event.data.action === 'skipWaiting'` but nothing happened and no log messages has been observed from the console.

Both files are residing under the same directory.

Comment: There's at least this bug: you're checking `event.data === 'skipWaiting'` instead of `event.data.action === 'skipWaiting'`.

Comment: Hi pate, Thanks for pointing out the bug! Ive amended the code but it seems like `service-worker.js/self.addEventListener('message', event => ...` is still not being called. Im not very sure if `service-worker.js` is being called at all so i added the following code to the top of the code:
`console.log("Im activated!")`. I didnt observed the message "Im activated" through the console

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial you linked, the code includes a call to reload the page but I do not see that in yours.

The reload is important because it allows the newly activated service worker to become the active worker once the page calls register. Alternatively you can use [Clients.claim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim) to let your new service worker take immediate control of existing pages.

Comment: Hi Justin, thank you so much for submitting your answer. I actually do have a `window.location.reload()`. Let me update my question and code again. I tried exploring the clients.claims() method as well but it seems like i need to put this code under my `service-worker.js`, which isnt being called at all